# Should touchID be displayed if app minimized

Tags: ios, ios8, touch-id

Im implementing touch ID to "unlock" my app, and im not sure if ive run into an apple bug or something i need to handle myself. If i tap the Home button and minimize my app before evaluatePolicy can load the Touch ID prompt, it appears over the home screen.

![not enough reputation to display screenshot, so heres a link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrhc60lx87ze7mt/IMG_0016.PNG

Successful/failure/cancel evaluation of this policy does nothing, but when i re-enter the app and cancel it again, touchID seems to be disabled forever until i restart the phone.

Anyone else running into this issue or have an ideas?

P.S. Theres an open radar where errSecUserCanceled is never returned from a cancel button tap, so right now i fall into my errSecAuthFailed case, which could also be the cause.

Comment: Daniel, I think you might be invoking Touch ID at the wrong time in the application life cycle. Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035546/touchid-calls-applicationwillresignactive-and-applicationdidbecomeactive/27557463#27557463

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. It should not be be displayed, when minimized.

The problem is IMHO that the code segment is being called again from your app when it goes to the background. For example loadView , didLoad and so on.

Try moving the code, that calls the authentication somewhere else in the program (different method).

For example, if your code uses a textView to enter password, you can implement the authentication within keyboardWillShow or similar.

Hope it helps.